# Install Boost from sources and compile with -fPIC option

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

we have boost already installed and we need to add a specific version of boost from sources.
Static libraries (`.a`) need to be compiled with `-fPIC` option and also we need CMake support.

Compiled and installed boost libraries will be used in projects managed by CMake. So, we need to make it easy to use them in C++ projects with CMake.

OS : Linux
, Compiler : GCC v4.8.x

What's the recommended why to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: Please expand on CMake support. Do you need CMake to handle the build or do you merely need CMake to use the libraries and initiate the build of the libraries if necessary?

Comment: Thanks. Description updated. The real need is to compile static libraries with - fPIC and to have support for CMake. Any good way is welcomed.